Excel macro VBA - select only top 3 rows on filtered data
Just wondering if someone could assist please?
I’ve used VBA to filter for product “Red” in column A and it has successfully returned 5 rows.
The next step is to use VBA to only copy the top 3 filtered results plus header
(row 1, 2, 7 and 10) to another sheet.
I’m having difficulties in getting the macro (tried offset) to select the Top 3 filtered range - it just selected row 1 to 4 rather than the filtered range (row 1,2 7,10).
I’ve no issues when selecting all the filtered rows, only stuck when I only want the Top3 filtered results.
Would someone be able to give me some pointers?
Thanks.
Sample below:



Row
ColumnA
Column B
Row




1.
Product
Team
1


2.
Red
1000.
2


7.
Red
2000
7


10.
Red
3000.
10


12.
Red
4000.
12


15.
Red
5000.
15



Sub top3()

    Selection.Autofilter
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="red"
    Range (“A1”). Select
    Range(activecell.offset(0,0),activecell.offset(3,2)).select
    Selection.copy
    Sheets(“Top3”).select
    Range (“A1”).select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False

End sub


Here's a Table Markdown Generator to make formatting tables easier (both for you and us). Also, try including the code you've used so far.


The filtered table could be non-contiguous.
Use nested loops to iterate through areas and rows to collect the target copying range.
Assume the table starts from cell A1.

Microsoft documentation:

Application.Union method (Excel)


Range.SpecialCells method (Excel)


Range.Areas property (Excel)

Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim visRng As Range, copyRng As Range, iR As Long
    Dim ColCnt As Long, rRow As Range, rArea As Range
    Const ROWS_COPY = 4  ' 3 rows + header
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        ColCnt = .Columns.Count
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Red"
        Set visRng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If Not visRng Is Nothing Then
            If visRng.Cells.Count / ColCnt > ROWS_COPY Then
                For Each rArea In visRng.Areas
                    For Each rRow In rArea.Rows
                        If copyRng Is Nothing Then
                            Set copyRng = rRow
                        Else
                            Set copyRng = Application.Union(copyRng, rRow)
                        End If
                        iR = iR + 1
                        If iR = ROWS_COPY Then Exit For
                    Next
                    If iR = ROWS_COPY Then Exit For
                Next
            Else
                Set copyRng = visRng
            End If
            Sheets.Add
            copyRng.Copy Range("a1")
        End If
        .AutoFilter
    End With
End Sub


Copy a Specific Number of Filtered Rows As Values

Sub CopyTop3()

    ' Define constants.
    Const COPY_ROWS_COUNT As Long = 3
    Const COPY_COLUMNS_COUNT As Long = 2
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source objects.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' ???
    sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    Dim srg As Range:
    Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, COPY_COLUMNS_COUNT)
    
    ' Reference the destination objects.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Top3")
    dws.AutoFilterMode = False
    Dim dfcell As Range: Set dfcell = dws.Range("A1")
    Dim drrg As Range: Set drrg = dfcell.Resize(, COPY_COLUMNS_COUNT)
    Dim dRowsCount As Long: dRowsCount = COPY_ROWS_COUNT + 1 ' headers
    
    ' Filter.
    srg.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="red"
    Dim sfrg As Range: Set sfrg = srg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim srrg As Range, dRows As Long
    
    ' Copy values.
    For Each srrg In sfrg.Rows
        drrg.Offset(dRows).Value = srrg.Value
        dRows = dRows + 1
        If dRows = dRowsCount Then Exit For
    Next srrg
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Copied " & dRows & " row" & IIf(dRows = 1, "", "s") _
        & " including headers.", vbInformation

End Sub

